# How to compile PIC microcontroller assembly code via command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, command-line, pic

I am using Microchip's MPASM compiler to program PIC microcontrollers in assembly language. However, I would like the option of using a text editor of my choice and compiling my code from the command line instead of compiling in the MPLAB IDE development environment.

My question is: Are there any alternatives or methods to compile assembly code for PIC microcontrollers outside of the MPLAB IDE environment using the MPASM compiler via the command line? I'd like to be able to write my code in a text editor and then compile it from the command line for more flexibility. (It doesn't necessarily have to be mpasm, it could be another compiler)

I would appreciate if anyone could provide information, examples, or resources that can help me achieve this goal.

Comment: many choices with or without mpasm.  how many have you tried so far?

Comment: e,g.https://www.mankier.com/1/gpasm

Comment: The answer to your question is complicated. Microchip no longer supports MPASM. The last time it was "officially" updated as MPLABX v5.35. New controllers are supported only by the assembler tool part (pic-as) of the XC8 C compiler. MPASM is a 32-bit application and does not work with Windows 11.

Comment: Depending on the Microchip controllers you will be creating source code for and if you plan to release the source code for public comment you may need to use only the Microchip supported tools.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://gputils.sourceforge.io/ and [gputils.pdf](https://gputils.sourceforge.io/gputils.pdf) here is `Makefile`

```
TARGET := firmware.hex

all: $(TARGET)

%.hex: %.o
    gplink --map --object --optimize 2 --output $@ $^

%.o: %.asm
    gpasm --object --output $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.lst *.map *.hex *.cod
```

```bash
sudo apt-get -y install gputils sdcc
```